# ¿Cómo creo un diccionario dentro de una clase?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo que hacer una clase con un solo atributo el cual debe ser un diccionario con id, nombre y email, pero no sé como hacerlo, he intentado así:

```
class Personal_Universitario:
    
    def __init__(self, personal={}):
        self.personal = {Id: "", nombre: "", email: "" }

A1 = Personal_Universitario({b1 : Id: 16, nombre: "jose", email:"jose@gmail.com"})
```

No sé muy bien como crear un diccionario dentro de una clase. He intentado así, pero a la hora de crear un objeto de esa misma clase no me funcionaba.

Answer (score 2):

En Python, los índices de diccionarios deben ser del tipado correspondiente. En tu caso es:

```
{"Id":num_entero, "nombre":"cadena1", "email":"cadena2" }
```

y para traer la información, es igual `obj.atributo["nombre"]`, etc...

Para inicializar el objeto a través del método `__init__` se puede hacer de varias maneras, pero la más sencilla diría que es mandando cada uno de los parámetros individualmente:

```
class Personal_Universitario:
    
    def __init__(self, ID, nombre, email):
        self.personal = {"Id":ID, "nombre":nombre, "email":email }

A1 = Personal_Universitario(16, "jose", "jose@gmail.com")
```

Para imprimir alguno de los datos:

```
print("Nombre:", A1.personal["nombre"]) # jose
```

Obviamente no será la forma más elegante de retornar e imprimir un valor, pero como solo tienes un método, es lo que hay.

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que quieres es que tenga un solo atributo y que sea un diccionario, puedes incluirlo igual que lo harías si se tratase de un número o una cadena:

```
class Personal_Universitario():
    def __init__(self, personal):
        self.personal = personal

A1 = Personal_Universitario({'Id': 16, 'nombre': "jose", 'email': "jose@gmail.com"})

print(A1.personal)  # Devuelve {'Id': 16, 'nombre': 'jose', 'email': 'jose@gmail.com'}
```

En caso que quieras pasar un diccionario pero luego quisieras tener sus claves como atributos, puedes crearlas de esta manera:

```
class Personal_Universitario():
    def __init__(self, personal):
        for k, v in personal.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)


A1 = Personal_Universitario({'Id': 16, 'nombre': "jose", 'email': "jose@gmail.com"})

print(A1.Id)  # Devuelve 16
print(A1.nombre)  # Devuelve jose
print(A1.email)  # Devuelve jose@gmail.com
```

En este caso te creará un atributo por cada clave que tenga el diccionario, por lo que podrías pasar diccionarios con distinta cantidad de datos.